# How get local root path in svn?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, mercurial, bazaar

Mercuril, Git and Bazaar has a way to get path root:

```
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
hg root 
bzr root
```

How print the local root path in subversion?

**Update**

Example:

```
> svn checkout https://example.com/svn/foo ~/foo --username fabiocerqueira
> cd ~/foo
> svn root (don't works)
  /home/user/project/foo/
```

Answer (score 4):

Would the `Working Copy Root Path` from the `svn info` command provide what you need?

```
D:> svn info
Path: .
Working Copy Root Path: D:\workdir\local-tc-common-all
URL: svn://localhost/trunk/tc-common-all/src/main/bin
Repository Root: svn://localhost
Repository UUID: 4f1d1789-e46b-c140-9c77-f79c92213374
Revision: 61
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: dweintraub
Last Changed Rev: 3
Last Changed Date: 2012-07-19 12:09:24 -0400 (Thu, 19 Jul 2012)
```

This gives you the root of the current checkout which seems to be what you're looking for. You can use the `--xml` switch which sometimes makes it easier to get programmatically since most programming languages are pretty good at parsing XML.

If you're looking for the **root** of the repository itself separate from the URL scheme, you could get that by taking the *Repository Root* out of the *URL* field.

Comment: `svn info` don't returns "Working Copy Root Path". What is the version of the subversion? My version is 1.6.18 (r1303927)

Comment: That example was cut from version 1.7 on Windows. However, I tried it with 1.6.18, and get the Repository Root path on the Mac.

Answer (score 3):

Did some search and found nothing... Finally I saw the old friend `svn info` and see if works for you...

```
$ svn info | grep 'Root'
Repository Root: http://your.subversion.com/path/to/root
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: "svn info" returns remote root path. I wanna get the path where I made the checkout. Example:

    > svn checkout http://example.com/svn/foo ~/foo
    > cd ~/foo
    > svn root (don't works)
      /home/user/project/foo/

Answer (score 0):

If you install the SlikSvn client, you can do a "svn info" at any level of the checkout and it will return the local root path.

Answer (score 0):

I use `svn info | awk -F: '/Root Path: (.*)/ { print $2 }' | xargs` on Linux and Windows through Cygwin.